# I can't understand polynomial in the book

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, linear-algebra

I'm reading a book called *Bishop - Pattern Recognition and Machine learning*.

I came across the following equation, in which I don't understand what $W$ stands for.
[image]

So, what is $W$?

Answer (score 2):

Without reading the book, my guess is
$W$ is a vector of weights(polynomial coefficients).  Assuming $x$ is the feature vector, I.E $x$ := {$x_1$, $x_2$, ... $x_n$} then W := {$w_1$, $w_2$, ... $w_n$}.

Comment: "Note that, although the polynomial function y(x, w) is a nonlinear function of x, it
is a linear function of the coefficients w." adopting from the book.

Comment: This agrees with my answer - W is the vector of given polynomial coefficients.